# Connecting to Project Online from Azure DevOps Extension

Tags: azure-devops, ms-project-server-2013, project-online

I have created a Azure DevOps hub extension, it retrieves work items and the goal is to then move some of the work item notes over to Project Online Timesheet Notes. But I can't figure out how I can authenticate my calls from the Azure DevOps Extension to be able to call Project Online.

It seems like the

```
.getAccessToken(...)
```

call in the sdk gets an access token encrypted with my extension data, but I need some way I can call into Project instead. I looked into MSAL and it seemed like a good option except I then need to register my extension as a SPA and I can't confirm where it will live.

I'm trying to avoid having the user provide user/pass, anyone know another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with Microsoft learned that this is not supported by Project Online. I was specifically trying to connect to the timesheet for Project Online and was told that it is not supported by the code.